# html:select in html:select? Is it possible?

Tags: select, struts, nested

Is it possible one of the options of html:select tag to be another select? And if not, how can I achieve this result using Struts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following code and run it in a few browsers:

```
<select>
    <option value="c0">Option c0</option>
    <option value="c1">
        <select>
            <option value="c1_prime_1">Option c1 prime 1</option>
            <option value="c1_prime_2">Option c1 prime 2</option>
        </select>
    </option>
    <option value="c2">Option c2</option>
    <option value="c3">Option c3</option>
</select>
```

You will find that the answer to your question is No!

Even if it were possible for Struts to have a html:select inside an html:option tag it would not matter since those tags output HTML and the result would be like the one above which does not deliver on what you want.

I guess you could mimic the functionality of a select with divs and javascript and display something that looks like a select with options that are other selects but that won't be a select with a select option, it will just look like one.